# How to make a link downloadable by clicking the left mouse button?

Tags: html

In this page I have a button which says download:

http://www.brianfunshine.com/newest-company-narration-demo/

The problem is that it opens the song in the browser it doesn't download the song.
How to solve that issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this to the top of your .htaccess file:

```
<FilesMatch “.(?i:(mp3))$”>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        ForceType application/octet-stream
        Header set Content-Disposition attachment
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

If you want to force download another type of file (say pdf?), just add it next to mp3, like this
 `<FilesMatch “.(?i:(mp3|pdf))$”>`

Answer (score 4):

HTTP header `Content-Disposition`

Comment: in your htaccess:
  <Files songname.mp3>
    Header set Content-Disposition attachment
  </Files>
(I felt this answer needed an explanation of application but didn't feel creating my own answer to be in the spirit of stack-ex)

Comment: @Chris Browne is the htaccess the only way to go?

Comment: @alexchenco: no, absolutely not.  PHP can be used to modify the header of the song, the server's main configuration file (if you have access to it) can be used.  There are a number of alternatives, but this is my recommendation as it is simplest and quickest.

Answer (score 0):

Content-disposition is an extension to the MIME protocol that instructs a MIME user agent on how it should display an attached file.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/260519

More specifically, it looks like "content-disposition: attachment; filename=[filename]" is what you want.

http://forums.iis.net/t/1162386.aspx

Answer (score -4):

- Right click on that button and
- Click on `save link as` it will open a `Save As Dialog Box`,
- Select ur location to save,
- When Download is complete you will be able to play your song.

Comment: Problem is, this requires users to be tech-literate. Rarely a reliable assumption.